# 2sxc Accept multiple files using one field in mobius forms

Tags: 2sxc

I am trying to customize the simple contact form with files example. The form currently has 2 input fields with the same name that gets sent over as an array of files.

Is there some sample code to use one input field that accepts multiple files and uploads them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no example to do that, and the current endpoint wouldn't do this by default, so you would have to make some changes to the endpoint to get this to work. For someone who knows c# it shouldn't be difficult, but if that's not your forte, I would go for multiple fields just because you will be able to get that to work.